# Tooltip-expansion of ALL username-mentions in comments (not just for previous commenter)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, display-names, tooltips

While writing a new comment, if one uses the "@username" syntax to mention a previous commenter, the system confirms that it recognizes this username by showing a tooltip expansion of the "@username".

It would be nice if this expansion were performed for *all* such "@username" mentions -- including the name of the post-owner, previous editor, or moderator.

One might make the case that such a feature is not needed, since the help for [Comment Formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) explicitly states that:

> The owner of the post you're commenting on will ***always*** be notified of your comment

and that:

> You can use the same method to notify any editor of the post, or – if this is the case – to the ♦ moderator who closed the question.

Nevertheless, I *still* think that this would be a nice feature.  Not everybody reads the official help.  And even after I did read the help, I still had lingering doubts after mentioning an editor in a comment, as to whether he was really notified or not.

Comment: Thanks, @Tim.  Yes, I agree that it is an EXACT duplicate.  I actually DID try searching MSO before posting my question, but I did not come across this particular one!